# Drop/edit rows in dataframe where entry doesn't meet condition

Tags: python, pandas

I know this has been asked before but I cannot find an answer that is working for me. I have a dataframe `df` that contains a column `age`, but the values are not all integers, some are strings like `35-59`. I want to drop those entries. I have tried these two solutions as suggested by [kite](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-%60dataframe%60-based-on-a-conditional-expression-in-python) but they both give me `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`

```
df.drop(df[df.age.isnumeric()].index, inplace=True)
```

```
df = df.query("age.isnumeric()")
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Additionally is there a simple way to edit the value of an entry if it matches a certain condition? For example instead of deleting rows that have age as a range of values, I could replace it with a random value within that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
df.drop(df[df.age.str.isnumeric() == False].index, inplace=True)
```

If you check [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) isnumeric is a method of Series.str and not of Series. That's why you get that error.

Also you will need the `==False` because you have mixed types and get a series with only booleans.

Comment: This worked thank-you! Do you have any suggestions on how to edit values that fit a certain criteria, for example `if age.str[2] == '-': replace with midpoint of two ages`

Comment: Also do you know why I cannot plot this column now on a histogram? I am getting the error `TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float`

Comment: For that you will need to develop a function that makes the fixes that you need and apply it for each value of age column with the Series.apply. For example, `df.age = df.age.apply(fix_age_col)`

Comment: brilliant, and fix_age_col(input) will have a string as an input? Thank-you for your help

Comment: Will have each value of the age column, you might receive ints, float, str, whatever your row has. Always try to keep rows types consistent. btw, idw about what you are trying to do with histograms

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting it in case this also helps you with your last question. You can use [pandas.DataFrame.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) with [pandas.DataFrame.Itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) for iteration over rows of the dataframe and replace values:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
  # iterate every row and change the value of that column
  if row.age == 'non_desirable_value:
    df.at[row.Index, "age"] = 'desirable_value'
```

Hence, it could be:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
  if row.age.str.isnumeric() == False or row.age == 'non_desirable_value':
    df.at[row.Index, "age"] = 'desirable_value'
```